# How to use data of MS Excel from External source into its activity?

Tags: android, excel

I have a application in which I wanted to extract the data from MS Excel sheets, and display this data in the activity as per its need. That MS Excel sheet will be in assets. Can you help me regarding this. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to link to data from another Excel workbook?  Is this an Android app?  Could you please provide [lots] more information?

Comment: yes.. it is the college management app..I want to display the data of MS Excel table in activity